# PAM with LDAP and add an exception for local user

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ldap, pam

I've successfully configured LDAP and SSH. Also I've added a requirement that user should be in a group called `admin`. That works.

## /etc/ldap.conf

```
...
pam_groupdn cn=admin,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
...
```

## /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
...default ubuntu values here...
...
auth     required pam_ldap.so
account  required pam_ldap.so
password required pam_ldap.so
session  required pam_ldap.so
```

BUT I would like to add an exception for local `backup` user in emergency case when LDAP is not reachable. This user has `sudo` and `authorized_keys`. How can I achieve that?

Right now I can see only this error message:

```
sshd[12345]: fatal: Access denied for user backup by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for our German friends from https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/pam-so-konfigurieren-dass-lokale-user-nicht-am/. The solution is:

```
# Allow local user or LDAP user from admin group
account sufficient pam_localuser.so
account required   pam_ldap.so
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which file should this be in?

Comment: `sed -i '1iaccount sufficient pam_localuser.so'  /etc/pam.d/login`. sed 1i as we need this in the first line